# Could a human being survive the lightning bolt that hit the Tenth Doctor in S3E4 "Evolution of the Daleks"?

Tags: doctor-who

During the episode "Evolution of the Daleks", the Tenth Doctor

> absorbed a lightning bolt (full of gamma radiation) from the top of
>  the Empire State Building in order to stop/delay/interfere with the dalek's
>  plan to create an army of human shells with Dalek minds

Now, the Doctor manages to come out virtually unscathed. I'm curious if a normal Earth human would be able to survive the same bolt, or if The Doctor was able to survive because he's a Time Lord who has regenerative powers (and can absorb radiation, seen in S3E2 "Smith and Jones").

NOTE: I've only watched up to S3E4, so please no spoilers.

I am looking for an in-universe explanation. Really what I'm looking for is if The Doctor was able to survive *only* because he's an alien or if there was some other factor in play.

Comment: I will post a mandatory comment stating that this is [on-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7367/70236). Just in case.

Comment: @Gallifreyan thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [BBC notes about the episode](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2016/09/doctor-who-10-things-you-may-not-know-about-evolution-of-the-daleks)

> The Doctor has demonstrated an ability to withstand huge electric shocks a few times, most notably in “Terror of the Zygons,” “World War Three”, “Genesis of the Daleks,” and “The Idiot’s Lantern.” He also described a shocking experience helping Benjamin Franklin in his experiments with a kite in “Smith and Jones.”

So, yes, he survived because he's a Timelord. No, this is not a regeneration. There's a proper accounting of all the Doctor's regenerations in a forthcoming episode and this was not listed as one.

Comment: Ah, nice! I wasn't sure if "regeneration" explicitly referred to "dying" and coming back as the next Doctor or if The Doctor had some kind of healing factor.

Comment: @ZipZapJ I could answer that for you, but as a future character (whom you have not yet met) likes to say "Spoilers..."